# Find all solutions of the equality $y^2=x^3+23$ for integers $x,y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find all solutions of the equality $y^2=x^3+23$ for integers $x,y$

I guess, that x cannot be even. because we can apply mod 4 test

say $x=2k$ then $y^2=8k^3+23\equiv3\mod(4)$

but, this is not possible, since the square of an integer is congruent to $0$ or $1$ $\mod (4)$

so $x$ is of the form $4k+3$ or $4k+1$

$x=4k+3$ is also not possible for the same reason but for the last case the test fails.

any hints ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are no integer solutions.

You noted already that $x$ cannot be even, because the equation would then
fail mod $4$; so we need only consider $x$ odd.  Then $x^3+23$ is even,
so must be a multiple of $4$, whence $x \equiv 1 \bmod 4$.

We cannot obtain a contradiction from further congruence considerations.
But since $23 = 3^3 - 2^2$ we try adding $4$ on both sides, getting
$$
y^2 + 4 = x^3 + 27 = (x+3) (x^2-3x+9),
$$
and observe that $x \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ implies
$x^2 - 3x + 9 \equiv 1 - 3 + 9 \equiv  3 \bmod 4$.
Since also $x^2-3x+9 > 0$ we deduce that $x^2-3x+9$ has a prime factor
$p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$.  But this is impossible by quadratic reciprocity:
$y$ would be a square root of $-4 \bmod p$.  **QED**

(In fact **mwrank** reports that there aren't even any rational solutions,
but that's not an elementary proof.)

[*Added later*: See Keith Conrad's
[Examples
of Mordell's Equation](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf)
for further examples of elementary but nontrivial proofs that certain
equations of this form $y^2 = x^3 + k$ have no integer solutions,
and also some examples where a nonempty list of solutions of $y^2 = x^3 + k$
can be proved complete.]

Comment: Can`t we conclude from the fact that if $x^3+23$ is a multiple of 4, so is $x^3+27$. If we factorize, like you did, $x+3$ must be $0mod4$ (if $x≡1mod4$) therefore $x^2−3x+9$ is multiple of 4, but this is always $3mod4$, which is a contradiction

Comment: How do you conclude from $x+3 \equiv 0 \bmod 4$ that $x^2-3x+9$
is a multiple of 4?

Comment: Sorry it was nonsense.

Comment: Why should there be a prime factor of the form $p = 3\bmod4$, also why is $y$ a square root of $-4\bmod p$?

Comment: @AuroraBorealis Odd primes are in the residue class $\{1, 3\} \mod 4$, which is closed under multiplication. Notice $1 \cdot 1 \equiv 1 \mod 4$. Thus, at least one of the primes in the prime expansion of $3 \mod 4$ must be congruent to $3 \mod 4$.

Comment: @AuroraBorealis Since $np=(x+3)(x^2−3x+9)$, we have $y^2+4 \equiv np \equiv 0 \mod p$.

Comment: @AuroraBorealis Finally, $\left(\frac{-4}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) \left(\frac{2}{p}\right)^2 = -1$ using the formula [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2755010/2736) for $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) $. Thus, $-4$ is a non-residue mod $p$.